# How to store selected <options> into PHP array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

So I'm trying to store the selected `<option></option>` tags into an array. I've searched everywhere and can't find any "Good" way of doing it.

```
<form action='most-liked.php'>
            <select multiple name='choose-category' style='display: inline-block;'>
            <?php
                $allCategories = ["All", "Sport", "Automotive", "Comedy", "Misc"];
                $htmlOutput = "";
                $i=0;
                    for($i;$i<sizeof($allCategories);$i++)
                    {
                        $htmlOutput .= "<option value='".$allCategories[$i]."'>".$allCategories[$i]."</option>";
                    }   
                echo $htmlOutput;
            ?>
            </select>
</form>
```

I was wondering if there is a way of adding the selected options into the `array` on the fly without reloading the whole page...E.g when they choose one of the `<option>`'s it's value will stored. Im thinking there may be a way of doing this with `jQuery`?

I was thinking maybe using a `$_GET[]` or something. But not too sure how  I'd do it.

Comment: Javascript/JQuery cannot directly interact with PHP. They can only do that by the `GET` or `POST` method, which can be done by either submitting a form, or using Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the `<select>` to:

```
choose-category[]
```

So your code will now look like:

```
<select multiple name='choose-category[]' style='display: inline-block;'>
```

Also, it is better to avoid `-`s in names, so this would be the right one:

```
<select multiple name='choose_category[]' style='display: inline-block;'>
```

And you can access it using:

```
$_REQUEST["choose_category"]
```

Which gives you an array!

Comment: Using that `$_REQUEST[]` Doesn't return anything? Do I have to put the `$_REQUEST[] ` inside an `if(isset($_POST['button'])){ echo $_REQUEST['choose_category']]}` for it to actually print?

Comment: No no,.. I just gave `$_REQUEST` in general. Use either `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: How would I print out the `selected` values with the form I have in my question and the changes that I've made with the `<select name='choose_category'>`? I can't seem to get it to actually print. 
Sorry Im not a huge expert in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

change your `select`

from

```
 <select multiple name='choose-category' style='display: inline-block;'>
```

to

```
<select multiple name='choose_category[]' style='display: inline-block;'>
```

now your `choose_category` is a array and when you will submit it. you will get a post `array` with all those values that were selected

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below using jQuery..

```
<form action='most-liked.php'>
            <select id="Category" multiple name='choose-category' style='display: inline-block;'>
            <?php
                $allCategories = ["All", "Sport", "Automotive", "Comedy", "Misc"];
                $htmlOutput = "";
                $i=0;
                    for($i;$i<sizeof($allCategories);$i++)
                    {
                        $htmlOutput .= "<option value='".$allCategories[$i]."'>".$allCategories[$i]."</option>";
                    }   
                echo $htmlOutput;
            ?>
            </select>
</form>
<script>
var foo = []; 
 $('#Category').change(function() {
     $('#Category :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
          foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
    });   alert(foo);
 }); 

</script>
```

Comment: I guess I could use this option if I was going to use AJAX?

Comment: yes to avoid reloading you should use Ajax or this type of js